Efficient Matching of Sample Requests to Sample Offers Using Large Language Models
I want to discuss an interesting matching problem. We aim to match sample requests with corresponding sample offers. Here are some examples:
Sample Requests:
Need help installing Linux on my old laptop.
Looking for a tutor in specialist mathematics.
Need a second person to help assemble an Ikea bed.
Sample Offers:
Electron Workshop and Linux Users Victoria Tech.
VCE maths tutor (Further, Methods, Specialist).
Heading from Lake Eildon to Melbourne. Anyone available?
To solve this problem, I used a large language model (LLM) to perform the matching. My approach involves embedding the requests and offers using vector embeddings and then employing a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) framework using LangChain. The method has shown promising results.
Here's a snippet of my code:
Initialize the OpenAI embeddings
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
Sample data
strings_to_embed = sample_off
Create Chroma vector store from the texts using the built-in embeddings
vector_store = Chroma.from_texts(texts=strings_to_embed, embedding=embeddings)
retriever = vector_store.as_retriever()
template = """ Match with the best offer based on the following context. Make different phrasing of the offer then search it.
Only return the matching answer.
No extra reasoning or string should be added:
{context}
Question: {question}
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=template)
rag_chain = (
{"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
| prompt
| ChatOpenAI()
| StrOutputParser()
)
Now to match the best request with the best offer, we invoke the RAG chain
rag_chain.invoke(sample_req[0])
While this method works well, I believe it may require too many LLM calls, which is not efficient. I am looking for ideas and discussions on how to improve this approach. Specifically, I want to explore how we can use the retriever more efficiently. For example, structuring the sample offers into different classes could potentially make the querying process more straightforward and efficient.
Any insights or suggestions on optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated!
